# Conditional list manipulation

Tags: conditional

I want to change a numerical list of the (examplary) form `{1,3/2,5}` to `{1,{1,2},5}`.

First solution

```
{3, 5/2, 1 } /.  Rational[a_ , b_] -> {Floor[a /b], Ceiling[a/b ]}  
(*{3, {2, 3}, 1}*)
```

works fine. Second try

```
{3, 5/2, 1} /. (in_ /; (! IntegerQ[in]) :> {Floor[in], Ceiling[in]}  )
(*{{3, 2, 1}, {3, 3, 1}}*)
```

fails.

What's wrong with my second version?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Replace` with level specification `1` gives the expected result:

```
Replace[{3, 5/2, 1}, (in_ /; (! IntegerQ[in]) :> {Floor[in], Ceiling[in]}), 1]
```

> {3, {2, 3}, 1}

With `ReplaceAll` the pattern `in_ /; (! IntegerQ[in])` matches `{3, 5/2, 1}` and it is applied to it to give `{Floor[{3, 5/2, 1}], Ceiling[{3, 5/2, 1}]}`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it!